# C# кидает исключение там, где его не может быть

Tags: c#, visual-studio, компиляция

Вне зависимости от того, как я переписываю код, VS2022 кидает CastException.

```
internal class AddListSlashCommandHandler : ICommandHandler
{
   private ModerationMode _moderationMode;

   public AddListSlashCommandHandler(SocketSlashCommand command)
   {
       _moderationMode = ModerationMode.NonModerated;
   }
}
```

Изначально строчка, с присваиванием выглядела так, с этоо все началось:

```
_moderationMode = (ModerationMode?)(long?)command.Data.Options.FirstOrDefault(op => op.Name == "moderation")?.Value;
```

ModerationMode

```
public enum ModerationMode
{
   NonModerated = 1,
   OnlyWarnings = 1 << 1,
   OnlyResend = 1 << 2,
   OnlyDelete = 1 << 3
}
```

Пробовал удалять папку Debug и Release. Переписывать это строку, если ее удалить, исключение кидается на следующей строке. До этого все работало нормально, потом я изменил _moderationMode на nullable  тип и понеслось. На скриншоте я уже поменял все обратно, но ошибка как была, так и осталась. Как перезагрузить проект, или если тут все же есть какое-то приведение, как его исправить?

Comment: Не вставляйте скриншот и покажите сигнатуру ModerationMode

Comment: public enum ModerationMode
    {
        NonModerated = 1,
        OnlyWarnings = 1 << 1,
        OnlyResend = 1 << 2,
        OnlyDelete = 1 << 3
    }

Comment: Вопрос отредактируйте и туда вставьте, а скриншот удалите (нужную часть кода из скриншота перенесите в вопрос). В комментарии не нужно прикреплять код

Comment: отредактировал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, ошибка бросалась на строчку выше и почему-то отображалась тут.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/824570)

Comment: Это 100% ответ на вопрос, который я задал. я разобрался и сам же и ответил. у кого такое же произойдет, поймет, что ошибка может быть на предыдущей строке (там действительно было кривое приведение) и не будет искать проблему там, где ее нет.